# How do I send a specific tag a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is what I have tried:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: {}".format(client.user))
    user = client.get_user('741143876563370086')
    await user.send("Hi") 
client.run('token')
```

However, It didnt work. I know that there is a simular question, but that one uses a command and I just want to send to a specific user.

Edit: I edited it with some new code

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you need to enable intents first, unlike other commands, this one is different on the `on_ready` event to dm a user. You can enable them on https://discord.com/developers/applications and then head over to your bot, then enable both on this pic below (sorry for bad circle things lmao)[image: e]

Now that you enable those, you can start coding.

we put our intents first before the `client`

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, members = True)
client = commands.Client(intents = intents)
```

More info about intents will be shown [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

alright, on `on_ready` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We are logged in as: {}".format(client.user.name))
    user = client.get_user(User_Id_Here) # You need to copy your user ID to make it work
    await user.send('Your Message Here') # Your message here, something like "Logged in!"
```

It works for me tho. [FAQ : How do I send a DM?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm)

Thank me later :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message to a specific user once the bot is started, you'll have to approach it a little differently.

`client.send` will always send something to a specific channel, but you want to have a `user` or `member`, you can define that as you like.

There is a function called `client.get_user()`, you can use this and **do the following:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We are logged in as: {}".format(client.user.name))
    user = client.get_user(YourID) # Insert the ID of the user
    await user.send("Hi") # Send the message
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried it I got this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`, any idea why?

Comment: @Tal Then the user does not exist. Have you inserted the right user ID?

Comment: yes, I have. Should I insert a tag instead?

Comment: @Tal No, you need an ID. Works fine for me. Which ID are you inserting? We can check if that is a valid user.

Comment: I am using `741143876563370086`, I have no clue why it isnt working.

Comment: The ID is valid. `NoneType` says that something was not found/does not exist. Have you restarted the bot? Is the user sharing a server with the bot? Can you make an edit with my answer so we can see how the code looks like? Maybe also a full error would be good.